# Watchman is getting failed to install because of folly library

Tags: watchman

I'm trying to install Watchman using Homebrew on macOS 10.15, but I'm encountering an error. Here's the command I ran and the output:

```bash
brew install watchman
And here's the error message I received:


==> Downloading https://formulae.brew.sh/api/formula.jws.json
##O#- #                                 ^
...
2 errors generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/folly_base.dir/folly/futures/ManualTimekeeper.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/folly_base.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

Do not report this issue to Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/homebrew-core!


Error: You are using macOS 10.15.
We (and Apple) do not provide support for this old version.
...
Try to figure out the problem yourself and submit a fix as a pull request.
We will review it but may or may not accept it.


I also tried installing the Folly dependency separately using 'brew install folly', but I still encountered the same error.

Platform Specification:
- macOS 10.15.7
- Xcode 12.4
- Homebrew 4.2.8
It seems like the error is related to compatibility with macOS 10.15. Is there a workaround for this issue?
```